# Java - How to replace this code with lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

is it possible to replace this code with a lambda expression?

```
repository.registerLoginHandler(new ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler() {
        public ILoginInfo challenge(ITeamRepository repository) {
            return new ILoginInfo() {
                public String getUserId() {
                    return "username";
                }
                public String getPassword() {
                    return "pass";                        
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

ILoginHandler is a functional interface:

```
ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler.ILoginInfo challenge(ITeamRepository repository)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
repository.registerLoginHandler(repo -> new ILoginInfo() {
    public String getUserId() {
        return "username";
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return "pass";                        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
repository.registerLoginHandler(repository -> {
    return new ILoginInfo() {
        public String getUserId() {
            return "username";
        }
        public String getPassword() {
                return "pass";                        
        }
    };
});
```

**Edit:** Other answer is more compact and therefore better.

Comment: Why `{return` ...`}`? We can skip this in lambda.

Comment: Yeah I just saw 3 returns and thought there is some logic there. I didn't realize that he just created a new class.